# Will an Australian Mastercard work on a UK PSN Account

Tags: ps3, psn

I know that you can't use an Australian Mastercard on a US PSN Account, i've tried but i'm wondering if a Australian Mastercard will work on a UK PSN Account since DLC for UK Games can be brought from the Australian PlayStation Store and work (I've tried with Tales of Graces F, Atelier Totori, Atelier Meruru, Hyperdimension Neptunia) so i figure maybe the UK Store will allow Australian Mastercard (or Visa Card)

i ask this as Agarest Generations of War Zero only has DLC in the UK Playstation Store and i'm wondering if i should waste more time trying to find UK PSN Cards or if i can just use my card

Comment: You can, but you might be charged a foreign exchange fee for purchases not in your domestic currency.

Comment: Your best bet is to try, if it doesn't work then you won't be charged. If it does work then you'll get DLC. As pointed out by @Krazer it is highly likely you will get a foreign exchange charge for converting AUD into GBP.

Comment: UK and Australia are part of the same region for PSN (EU region). Are you sure the DLC isn't in the Australian store? Sometimes there are slight differences between the stores but this is usually because of delays due to ratings, and most of these fix themselves in time.

Comment: @YellowMegaMan This isn't true, the australian store is a distinct entity and is more similar to the USA store than the UK one. Mainly because the Australian censorship laws are far more stringent/ridiculous.

Comment: @Colin: It's a distinct entity, but it still falls under the EU region and (mostly) gets the same updates, with the exception of games that can't be rated and are yet to be rated. PSN updates are announced on the EU blog (eg. http://blog.eu.playstation.com/2013/05/01/heads-up-playstation-store-update-1st-may-2013/ - see the list of countries: AE, **AU**, **GB**, IE, **NZ**). Finally, the PSN+ instant library for AU is the same as the rest of EU. The AU store is *most definitely not* similar to the US store. The content of these stores is very different.

Comment: @YellowMegaMan yes, as i have stated in the question, Agarest Generations of War's DLC is not Available in Australia but it is available in the UK, in another question i ended up answering myself, Ghostlight hasn't released the DLC in Australia because it wasn't submitted for an OFLC rating and it needs that to be sold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently it doesn't, a work around is however OZ Game Shop where you can buy UK PSN Cards and they always try to keep up stock of the cards

Comment: If you don't mind waiting a bit for postage, I would recommend buying your UK PSN cards from BlahDVD. They offer reasonable prices. While most online shops raise thew prices a bit for PSN cards, these actually cost cheaper than their value since you're excluded from tax.